# macos WKWebView - Debugging not possible anymore after archiving the app

Tags: macos, wkwebview

I have a macos app that mostly displays a WKWebView into which a webapp is loaded. I need to send a build of this app that has Safari debugging enabled out to other developers. Up until Xcode 10 i could do the following:

- Create another scheme
- Set the archive build configuration for that scheme to "Debug"
- Have an entitlements file for debug configurations with the key "com.apple.security.get-task-allow"
- Sign the app with a "Mac Developer" certificate and no provisiong profile
- Archive the app with said scheme
- Send the .app file out, it would still be debuggable in Safari

After upgrading to XCode 11 this does not work anymore. Safari only shows "No Inspectable Applications" and when i examine the app with `codesign -d --entitlements :- MyApp.app` the key "com.apple.security.get-task-allow" is just missing.

I also tried changing the signing to use a specific provisiong profile with my mac added to it, but that didnt change anything

Is there any way to get this to work again or do I have to change the build process to just not use archive anymore?

Comment: Same here. If I run through xcode (debug OR release) then Web Inspector can debug my WkWebview.  If I export the archive I can't run Web Inspector on the app (again, debug OR release). This is unhelpful for our web developers who shouldn't have to build from source.get-task-allow has been stripped from the archive build